# best graphical widget to define a range within a range

Tags: javascript, user-experience, web

I am developing a web page using HTML, JavaScript and CSS.

I have a range (e.g. 1,10000) I want the user to choose a sub-range (e.g. 1000-2800)

What's the best way to do this? Is there some kind of slider or similar?

At the moment I am using two textfields and do some validation but that's far from a nice UX.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about some sort of range slider?

Here's a jQuery one for you

http://ghusse.github.com/jQRangeSlider/stable/demo/

Comment: fair enough. it does what I want. I am not sure about the UX, but it works functionally. Ta

Answer (score 0):

Check out [this jQuery UI demo](http://jqueryui.com/demos/slider/#range).

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [jQuery UI slider](http://jqueryui.com/demos/slider/#range). It has an option to choose a sub-range.